# Is the least steps challenge map 11 in Portal Still Alive possible?

Tags: portal

I can get to the beginning of the big piston maze in 25 steps, sometimes 20, but I can't get from there to the end in the required 60 for the gold medal.

Are there any strategy to get through this last part? I've been trying bunny hopping with the crouch and I usually get 70+ steps.

Comment: I found [a video of someone doing it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kUKhh9lQMUI) but they use an out-of-bounds glitch, so I don't think that counts.

Comment: Yes, I've been following their videos, but that map has no video for a glitchless solution.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up doing this trick, don't know how it's called, this guy does it at 0:55 in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=l7RACdzSwwU), I stood inside a portal inside the first piston hall, quickly shot a portal to the next hall but immediately stepping off. And then the next one, and the next, until you're in the last hall.